# Erro com date time

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

Pessoal estou tentando executar meu código, estou tendo o seguinte erro: 
TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not subscriptable

Como faço para resolver isso?

seguem meu código abaixo:

```
def making_date(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.result = c.execute("SELECT * from inventory")

    for row in self.result:
        self.date1 = row[3]
        self.date2 = row[4]

        self.date1 = datetime.strptime(self.date1,'%d/%m/%Y').date()
        self.date2 = datetime.strptime(self.date2,'%d/%m/%Y').date()

        if self.date1[0:3] >= 2018:
            self.minus = abs((self.date1 - self.date2).days)
            self.mounth = self.minus // 30
            self.year = self.mounth // 12
            print(self.year)
```

irei mandar a foto de meu banco de dados caso ajude:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que o erro está em `self.date1[0:3]`. Se você quer o ano, e `self.date1` é um datetime, imagino que o correto é fazer `self.date1.year`.

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Deu esse erro ai, tenho que mudar o 2018 agora.

Comment: tentei colocar como string, mas deu esse erro

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Se fizer `if self.date1.year >= 2018:` ele da o erro `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`?

Comment: deu certo aqui, obrigado!

Comment: outro erro, que vai estar em outra linha (e não está errado no código acima). Veja a resposta abaixo - inclui uma parte que fala sobre como ler uma mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 2):

Sempre que o erro  `TypeError ... object is not subscriptable` aparece é por que o código está tentando usar o operador `[ ]` em um objeto que não é uma sequência ou um mapa.

E no seu caso, na linha

```
 self.date1 = datetime.strptime(self.date1,'%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

Você faz o atributo `self.date1` ter uma data  (um `datetime.date` do Python). Até faria sentido que objetos do tipo data funcionassem como sequências (e portanto, pudessem ser usados com `[...]`) eles poderiam ser uma sequência de ano, mes, dia. Mas não são. E não vem ao caso, por que na linha que acarreta o seu erro você coloca:

```
if self.date1[0:3] >= 2018:
```

Ou seja, você quer olhar os 4 primeiros elementos da "sequência" `self.date1`, como se ela fosse uma string. Mas ela não é uma string, é um objeto do tipo data. Se quiser o ano, basta pegar o atributo `.year`:

```
if self.date1.year >= 2018:
```

E você não terá mais esse erro. O Padrão SQL guarda a data de forma que ela pode funcionar como string e como data de forma meio misturada - por que históricamente foi ficando assim. Mas com do lado do Python seus dados são objetos de Python, e datas são datas, não são strings - então não podem ser recortadas como se fossem uma string, com `[0:3]`.

Uma outra dica é, quando tiver um erro, ler a mensagem de erro com atenção - além da parte que você colou na pergunta, nas linhas anteriores o Python exibe a linha exata que deu erro - e que funções anteriores chamaram a função atual onde aconteceu o erro. Possivelmente você teria conseguido achar o problema se tivesse olhado a linha correta. Mas se mesmo assim preferir perguntar, lembre-se de colar a mensagem de erro toda - num caso mais complexo pode ser difícil adivinhar o erro só com a mensagem de erro, sem saber *onde* ele ocorreu.

(dica 2: "mês" em inglês não tem "u"- é só "month". E não é como algumas palavras que em inglês britânico tem o "u", como "colour").